# How do I update LibreOffice?

Tags: updates, libreoffice

I've tried "sudo apt install libreoffice", using 18.04.10, but I still have version 6.0.7 after restarting the PC.  (I'm trying to get 6.20 or higher so I can simply rotate an image in Draw.)  I tried again but the terminal says "libreoffice is already the newest version (1:6.0.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.10)."  Do I have to try to change to Ubuntu 20.04 first or should I try downloading version 7.0 from the LibreOffice website?

I found online advice about automatic updates but this assumes I can open LibreOffice.  I've only discovered how to open individual programs such as Draw which don't seem to have an Online Update menu option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo snap install libreoffice
```

This command installs LibreOffice 7.0.4.2 in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu. LibreOffice includes several applications that make it the most versatile free and open source office suite on the market: Writer (word processing), Calc (spreadsheets), Impress (presentations), Draw (vector graphics and flowcharts), Base (databases), and Math (formula editing). The LibreOffice snap package will receive automatic updates when they become available.

Comment: After this, you'll end up with having two different LibreOffice versions installed.

Comment: You can use either the snap package or the apt package when they are installed alongside each other, and you can remove either the apt package with `sudo apt remove` or the snap package with `sudo snap remove` without interfering with the normal functioning of the other LibreOffice package(s) which are still installed.

Comment: That's great thanks.  I've now got version 7.  I can hardly wait to encounter the next problem.

Comment: @Andrew If this answered your question, you can mark this answer as accepted by clicking the gray check mark beside the answer to change its color to green.

Comment: @karel please, on 20.04.1 I do have the Libreoffice (v6.4.6.2) suite installed, yet when I issue the `sudo apt remove libreoffice --dry-run` command (just to test it), it returns: `Package 'libreoffice' is not installed, so not removed`. I have a bunch of related packages, like `libreoffice-common`, `libreoffce-core`, `libreoffice-gtk3` and so on. Which specific package-name should I give apt as an argument to ensure that it removes the entire suite, and could you please reveal the thinking that leads to that solution?

Comment: libreoffice is a metapackage, and is not installed by default so it's not removable. To uninstall all currently installed libreoffice packages run `sudo apt remove '^libreoffice'` This command will show you a list of libreoffice packages to be removed first before it removes any packages.

Answer (score 7):

Use a [3rd-party software repository (ppa)](https://launchpad.net/%7Elibreoffice/+archive/ubuntu/ppa?field.series_filter=bionic) for `apt`.
It currently provides the latest `libreoffice` for all LTS versions and the latest non-LTS:

```bsh
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:libreoffice/ppa
sudo apt upgrade
```

Current version is `7.0.4`

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply.  The download ended with several "Possible missing firmware" messages.  After restarting I still appear to have version 6.0.7.3 so I'll try using snap but I'm not hopeful.  I waste a lot of time trying to do the simplest things in Ubuntu.

Comment: One note, this is official PPA.